# Mongo DB Cursor issue while iterating over a huge collection

Tags: java, performance, mongodb

I am iterating over a Mongo DB collection. This collection has millions of documents in it. I am using java API for this iteration. This iteration exercise can go on for a while and we dont want to impact performance of the application. So we are planning to use Thread.sleep during this iteration. But we are facing cursor timeout kind of problems. Anyone faced this before? Also, is it possible to read data in chunks e.g. 100 documents at a time?

Comment: The cursor only returns in chunks anyway, but if you want to manually manage it you can set skip and limits, like in a SQL query, e.g http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a cursor over the entire collection you can try paging through the collection by the _id. So each time query for 100 documents (order by _id) and keep the last _id you encounter. Then on each consecutive query use a condition to fetch documents where _id > last _id from previous fetch.

Comment: The cursor will automatically page for you, it won't fetch all of them from the server in one go.  The cursor only returns 101 documents in the first fetch, and will invisibly go back to the server to request more if required (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/).  So there's no need to manually page in this way

Comment: Or if you really must paginate manually, use skip and limit in combination.

Comment: Skip and limit will not give a good performance in the deep pages over a large collection as skip still needs to actually skip over the previous results.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RotemHermon and Trisha. I agree with Trisha, why should we do a manual paging if mongo internally does that for you. Also, I saw an API call like setBatchSize(). Looks like we can set page size using this setBatchSize() as well. RotemHermon - Any compelling reason for doing this paging on our own?

Comment: If you experience cursor timeouts, which was your original concern. If you don't have timeouts problem then the cursor is fine, if you do that is the way to handle it.